# Is it possible to get a \rule to scale with different font sizes?

Tags: fontsize

Is it possible to have a vertical line drawn with `\rule` scale appropriately when using different font sizes? For instance, can one have `\Huge` make the `\rule` bigger to the same extent that it makes a single character bigger? Or by using a package such as `relsize`? I've tried both these things, and neither of them works. I've even tried putting it inside a `\section{...}` title, but that didn't work either.

Would it somehow be possible to draw a line with tikz instead and then scale that?

Comment: Try using lengths in units of `em` or `ex`.

Comment: There is also `\baselineskip`,  `\ht\strutbox` and `\dp\strutbox`,

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\RULE}{}{\rule{0.05em}{\fontcharht\font`A}}

\begin{document}

A\RULE B\RULE c

{\LARGE A\RULE B\RULE c\par}

{\LARGE\bfseries A\RULE B\RULE c\par}

\end{document}
```

This makes the rule as high as an uppercase letter. Change to your liking. Note that using `em` as the unit for the thickness, this reflects the current font weight. Use a fixed thickness if this isn't what you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I realized what was wrong, because apparently as long as you pass the width and height in units of `ex` or `em`, `\rule`'s *do* resize with font sizes such as `\Huge`. The problem was that I was creating lengths to hold the width and height of the `\rule`:

```
\newlength{\rulelength}
    \setlength{\rulelength}{1.3ex}
\newlength{\rulewidth}
    \setlength{\rulewidth}{0.15ex}
\newlength{\boldrulelength}
    \setlength{\boldrulelength}{1.3ex}
\newlength{\boldrulewidth}
    \setlength{\boldrulewidth}{0.25ex}
```

when instead I should have been creating commands:

```
\newcommand{\rulelength}{1.3ex}
\newcommand{\rulewidth}{0.15ex}
\newcommand{\boldrulelength}{1.3ex}
\newcommand{\boldrulewidth}{0.25ex}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, as usual here, show us a short *compilable* TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: @Mensch oh, sorry